# UITableView won't display information from array

Tags: swift, uitableview

So I'm trying to create a tableview and a cell won't show up.  Other than not appending anything to the recipes array, is there anything blatantly wrong with my code?

If this means anything, when I try to link the tableview to my code, it doesn't give me the opportunity to create an outlet.  [Github link here](https://github.com/Wsoren1/Recipe-Manager)

I'm New to iOS programming so this might be a dumb question, sorry if that's the case.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var recipes : [Recipe] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self


}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.title!

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipes.count
}


func createRecipe() -> [Recipe] {
    let recipe1 = Recipe()
    recipe1.title = "Test"
    recipe1.instructions = "testing"
    recipe1.time = "testing"

    let recipe2 = Recipe()
    recipe2.title = "Test2"
    recipe2.instructions = "testing"
    recipe2.time = "testing"

    return [recipe1, recipe2]
}



}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved your bug?

Comment: @Hitesh yes, The problem was I was trying to pull from coreData without saving anything to coreData.  I answered my own question below.  Thanks for your submission!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't saving to coreData as the `Recipe` class was created in coreData, and I wasn't saving anything from the `createRecipe` function.

Here's the fixes

New Function:

```
  func getRecipes() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        recipes = try context.fetch(Recipe.fetchRequest()) as! [Recipe]
        print(recipes)
    } catch {
        print("ERROR")
    }

}
```

Revised `createRecipe()`

```
func createRecipe() -> [Recipe] {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let recipe3 = Recipe(context: context)
    recipe3.title = "test3"
    recipe3.instructions = "testing"
    recipe3.time = "testing"
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)


    return [recipe3]
}
```

And the viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    recipes = createRecipe()
    getRecipes()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign Recipe Class Array in viewDidLoad and In cellForAt assign UITableviewCell

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    recipes = createRecipe()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.title!

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Turned out it was mainly an error in coreData.  Was trying to pull saved data from something I never saved anything to.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `createRecipe()`? Where are you adding recipes to your `recipes` array? I think what you meant was to write  `recipes = createRecipe()` in your `viewDidLoad`. Additionally to be sure your tableView is loaded with the latest data, add `tableView.reloadData()`
 as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    recipes = createRecipe()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Otherwise your `recipe` is would be just an empty array which translates to 0 rows...

Comment: Turned out it was mainly an error in coreData.  Was trying to pull saved data from something I never saved anything to.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is within your storyboard. Your controller is not `ViewController` is a basic `UIViewController`. So you need to change the type from `UIViewController` to `ViewController` and link your `tableView` after. That's why I didn't work when you were trying to link it the first time. I uploaded an image to be clear.[image]

Comment: Turned out it was mainly an error in coreData.  Was trying to pull saved data from something I never saved anything to.  Thank you for your help!